# Revert the animation backwards CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an animation going one direction. I want to revert it backwards (i.g. animate to the original position):

```js
$('#right').click(function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('.move-left').addClass('move-right');
});
$('#left').click(function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('.move-right').addClass('move-left');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.move-right {
  animation: move-right 10s linear;
}
.move-left {
  animation: move-left 10s linear;
}
@keyframes move-right {
  to {
    transform: translateX(500px);
  }
}
@keyframes move-left {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">Right right first</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/GWVbjv

This one doesn't work (because I think I need to save the current `translate` position, which gives me unexpected results when I then resize the page). Is there any bulletproof solution? (`animation-direction` doesn't seem to be the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the same value as starter for the *left* animation, also use `forwards` to keep the final state of the animation:

```js
$('#right').click(function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('move-left').addClass('move-right');
});
$('#left').click(function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('move-right').addClass('move-left');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.move-right {
  animation: move-right 2s linear forwards;
}
.move-left {
  animation: move-left 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes move-right {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
@keyframes move-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  },
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">Right right first</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

---

#### Bonus

If your goal is to just move the element that way you may prefer to use `transition` check the snippet below, that will allow you to use the buttons when the transition is happen on your first code if you press the buttons will jump to make the animation from the last point.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('id')=="right") {
    $('.container').addClass('move')
  } else {
    $('.container').removeClass('move')
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  transition:transform 2s linear;
}
.move {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">Right right first</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

---

## Jquery animate()

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('id')=="right") {
    $('.container').stop().animate({'left':'200px'},2000)
  } else if($(this).attr('id')=="left") {
    $('.container').stop().animate({'left':'0'},2000)
  } else {
    $('.container').stop()
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="right">Right right first</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a jump when I decide to change the direction in the middle of the animation. That's the main issue!

Comment: @sdvnksv check the bonus ... I have edited my question

Comment: @sdvnksv the option with the first code will be disable the buttons until the animation finish

Comment: Ah, the second sample is almost what I was looking for! I didn't think of combining transition and animation. The problem is that I also need the possibility to pause the container in the current position (e.g. have a "pause" button too). That's OK if you don't have a solution for this one, this is a great help anyway!

Comment: @sdvnksv that will require a little more time :P ... I can help U tomorrow if you don't have any answer then. But if yu want it to behave that way then will be more easy to go with jquery animate

Comment: I am animating a huge image in reality, so jQuery animation is not that smooth (I already tried that). This is a good start anyway!

Comment: I can actually simply set `animate-play-state` to `paused` on the pause button click, and copy the rest from your sample with some additions to set it to `running` when clicked to move `right`. Though it won't pause the `transition`. But I will handle that. Thanks!